# last.fm how to use Scrobbler gem in irb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, last.fm

I'm trying to test out scrobbler/scrobbler2 gem (http://scrobbler.rubyforge.org/) in irb. The problem I'm having is that every time I try to run it in **irb**, I get the following error:

--

```
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.9)  
>> album = Scrobbler::Album.new('Carrie Underwood', 'Some Hearts', :include_info => true)
NameError: uninitialized constant Scrobbler from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in 
`load_missing_constant' from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in 
`const_missing' from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:118:in `const_missing'
```

--

I dont understand this error, can someone point me in the right direction?

MANY THANKS!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you require it ?

```
require 'scrobbler'
```